# Getting started with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to do the labs on TestFirst.org with rspec. I've installed rspec and initilized it in the project directory. But when i "rake" i get this error message:

```
 Could not find 'rspec' <~> 2) - did find: [rspec-3.0.0]
 C:/Sites/RubyTest/RubyTesting/learn_ruby/rakefile:2:in `<top (required)>´
```

My versions:

```
  ruby 1.9.3p545
  rails 4.1.1
  rspec 3.0.2
```

Seems like I've got the wrong version of rspec or something. My OS is windows 7 btw.

This is the content of rakefile:

```
     gem 'rspec', '~>2'
     require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

     task :default => :spec

     desc "run tests for this lab"
     RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |task|
     lab = Rake.application.original_dir
     task.pattern = "#{lab}/*_spec.rb"
     task.rspec_opts = [ "-I#{lab}", "-I#{lab}/solution", '-f documentation', '-r        ./rspec_config']
     task.verbose = false
     end
```

Comment: What is the content of rakefile? Is it requiring the right version?

Comment: Edited and added rakefile.

Comment: Change it to gem 'rspec', '~>3'

Comment: I have added it as an answer. Please accept if it solved the issue. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `rspec ~3.0.0` is already activated and your rake file requires `'rspec', '~>2'`. Change rspec version in Rakefile to fix this.

```
gem 'rspec', '~>3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a installed version of rspec (3.0.2) that is more recent than the one expected by the project (~ 2.x).

One simple way to solve it would be to force bundle to use the project version:

```
bundle exec rake
```

(instead of just using rake)

Comment: Tried this out. But it says: can't activate rspec <~> 2). already activated rspec-3.0.0